# PIC16F1454 response a hos request over 64 bytes problem

Tags: usb

I have a problem with PIC16F1454. On enumeration stage, I can use ep0 to response most of host requests and connect successfully, but problem when response from device > 64 bytes. I have device using over 64 bytes response (160 bytes) but ep0 maximum size is 64. I tried to do something follow:

1. split big desc buffer to 3 transfers (64,64,32). when host request(wLength = 0xA0), I sent one by one -> result: host received only first pack and flush OUT pack and reset device -> failed enumerate
2. trying to create a ep0 tx buffer with length = 170 bytes. when host request, send all buffer -> result: host received 160 bytes successful but more byte worng and wrong CRC, this request retry 3 times and same error(bad CRC) -> device reset -> enumeration failed

With section 2, I think RAM map of pic16F1454 for USB only 80 bytes each bank, if I create 170 buffer, this has something out of USB RAM setion and USB address can't point to these section -> data wrong (is it right?)

So anyway to response an over 64 bytes when host request? please help!
Thank all!

find out the ways to resolve my problem